# Display Close Reasons to New Users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close

Example: "Is there a library/plugin.."

We see this question hundreds of times a week.

Perhaps either until a certain rep, a new user has to pass a "close vote" test to post a question?

"Does your question fall under any of these categories?" --> read the close votes

That or/and have a little program run that detects certain phrases like..

```
plugin
library
is there a library/plugin
```

Either in the title or body. That's only specific for the off-topic library reason though.

Anything to disuade these one sentence questions..

Comment: I imagine most users will simply learn that the only way to post their question is to say "no" whenever they see a prompt like this, so they'll just stop reading them after the first or second time (best case).

Comment: @Servy and they'll be promptly closed. But this could stop the "Oh sorry, I didn't see it" excuses

Comment: To be honest, I don't actually see a whole lot of people post, "Oh, I didn't know that wasn't allowed" very often when their questions are closed.  (Which is not to say that everyone knows they're violating the rules when posting, simply that they seem to know ignorance is not a valid excuse.)

Comment: Hmm, that is true. They usually get rather upset that we simply didn't write a plugin for them :(

Comment: We need what you suggested and "I need a tutorial for..." Or "How to learn..."

Comment: and "not working"/"doesn't work" - The majority of the time I see these used I know there is a close vote of mine ready to follow it. Note: that you can get valid questions that involve these phrases (and the ones you have suggested) so they shouldn't be banned completely

Comment: I think a notification of a close vote would benefit.  Or at least a more prominent notice that votes to close are taking place.  That gives the asker notice so they can edit their question.

Comment: I think this question should be closed as too broad—flagged now.

Comment: Is it always bad to ask for a plugin? E.g. my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23409643/intellij-13-wont-keep-line-breaks-when-reformatting-javascript - I found an answer myself but it required a plugin, and I had already said I'd be happy to accept a plugin - does that make it off-topic (at the risk of having my own question closed). Hmmm, should I have posted a new meta question instead of this comment? :)